# point a subfolder to another IP with Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdirectory

If a user visits `www.example.com/forum` could this point to another server/IP without changing the actual URL the user sees?
This means that every request after that must pass to the other server while sending all the post/get data so that `www.example.com/forum/index.php?some=thing` must work as if it was `myothersite.example.com/forum/index.php?some=thin`

edit: all this is because the registrant doesn't allow to manage DNS records or even create subdomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible - you'd have to make Apache [act as a Proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) for this to work, and this brings other problems:

- All traffic would have to run through both sites
- On shared hosting, you probably won't be allowed to do this
- `REMOTE_ADDR`, cookies and other things would no longer work as expected

the best you can do is create a set of `RewriteRule`s that will do header redirects to the target domain. However, in that scenario, the target domain/IP will always be visible to the end user.